# Notepad++ XML autocompletion / add end tag?

Tags: xml, autocomplete, notepad++

In Notepad++ (latest version 6.1.2), is there any auto completion for XML (in terms of automatically add closing tag)?

E.g. when typing

```
<test>
```

I want Notepad++ to automatically add

```
</test>
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: There's a plugin called "XML Tools" which you can get via Notepad++'s plugin manager. 
There's an option there called "Tag auto close", which adds the end tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know there is an HTML plugin that is included in the recent versions which does some tag closing for you. But I haven't heard of a XML one. There is probably one out there though if you look. But if not, its not too hard to write a plugin using C#, if you have it.

Comment: Hmm OK, was just wondering if I missed a setting for this / it's already built in. Will stay at Eclipse for XML (also requires plugin for auto completion).

Answer (score 22):

First, download the TextFX plugin using Plugin Manager

```
Plugins > Plugin Manager
```

Then select the following menu

```
TextFX > TextFXSettings > Autoclose XHTML/XML <Tag>
```

Comment: Just so its obvious, you have to download TextFX via the plugin manager first.

Comment: Perfect.  How do we get this as the accepted answer since the one right now doesn't apply?

Answer (score 13):

For newer versions of Notepad++ try

```
Preferences > Auto Completion > Auto Insert > html/xml close tag
```

Note that the file extension must be `.xml, .html, etc.` for this feature to activate. I'm not sure when this feature was introduced but it is in v6.7.9.

Comment: More exactly, the language of the file (which can be changed in the Language menu) must be either HTML or XML. So you could have a `.php` file with the language changed to HTML and the autocomplete will work. That's a shame. The best solution is to use the TextFX plugin as noted in the answer by Hoa.

Comment: Thanks,
I had an issue with duplicate closing XML tags because both Notepad++ and XMLTools plugin were adding it.

Answer (score 4):

`XML Tools` from the `Plugin Manager` can do the trick as well. Then once download the plugin, tick `Tag auto-close` in `Plugins > XML Tools`